# Hystrix and http sink (Connection Pooling) working together

Tags: connection, microservices, connection-pooling, hystrix

What is the default timeout values for hystrix and Apache HTTPConnection Pooling Http Sink?

If you have a service that is using Hystrix and also HTTP Sink together and if you do not specify the timeout config values in manifest.yml, which will take precedence - the Hystrix default values or Http sink default values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussions with various SME, it is inferred that Hystrix timeouts have precedence over your individual rest/soap clients or connection pools.